# CMake error on building FlightGear

Tags: windows, cmake

I am trying to build FlightGear project using CMake and following the directions line by line found in the article [here](http://wiki.flightgear.org/Superbuild_on_Windows) I am building on windows. I click Configure on CMake, select my code generator and then I get this error messages

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:2140 (get_property):
  get_property could not find TARGET WinDeps.  Perhaps it has not yet been
  created.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:2476 (_ep_add_configure_command)
  CMakeLists.txt:84 (ExternalProject_Add)
```

Any idea what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Looks like a FlightGear problem. Have you checked whether someone fixed it already or opened an issue? If not, ask on their mailing list. This question is kind of too specific for SO.

Comment: It does look like it yes, but I was just wondering if this Cmake error happened to anyone else on a different project and what it means

Comment: There is a CMake command `get_property`. It is used to get properties from targets, sources, tests, directories and so on. When you call it for a target that was not defined, CMake errors out. So something goes wrong with the creation of the target or the get_property line should not be called under the circumstances on your system. Documentation about the command: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/get_property.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windeps is no longer defined as part of flightgear so I removed the command

```
list(APPEND OSG_DEPS WinDeps)
```

from `CMakeLists.txt` and build was successful